# Build release APK giving the error ':background_fetch:verifyReleaseResources' and others

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin

Hello everything is fine? I need help please! I'm trying to compile the APK of my Flutter app, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':background_fetch:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:...app\build\background_fetch\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:2520:AAPT:error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

```
┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ ..............................................app\android\build.gradle:                           │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The strangest thing is that when I try to compile the App Bundle, it works normally, by the way, the app is already available for download on Google Play. However, because of some bugs I'm trying to compile the APK to test on an external emulator before updating (since the Android Studio emulator already comes with the permissions allowed, and I needed to test just that).

My Buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Upon receiving this error, I changed the kotlin_version to '1.8.21', so I started to receive several errors like the following:

```
C:/Users/mathe/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.21/d749cd5ae25da36d06e5028785038e24f9d37976/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.
The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

Okay, I understood that what was expected was kotlin 1.6.0. After changing the kotlin version in the buildscript, giving the command "flutter clean" and "flutter build apk --release", again, I get several similar compilation errors, they are more or less like this:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
...
Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

I entered this link to check and I was extremely lost. I read it and couldn't understand what I need to do. I didn't understand which files I need to fix or what I should do.

What makes me more uncomfortable is that the App Bundle build works perfectly, but the release apk does not. Can someone help me? I don't know what else to do, thanks.